# Extending a python list class to perform additional functions on its contents?

Tags: python, oop, list, python-3.x

I want to create an object which will hold other objects, and call a method on each of the objects it holds. The end goal is to generate a script for a program. Each object contains a command that can be printed with `printCommand()`, eventually into a file. My original solution was this:

```
a = ObjectList()
a.appendObject(Object())
b = ObjectList()
b.appendObject(Object())

listOfObjects = [a, b]
for Object in listOfObjects:
    Object.printCommand()
```

I create a list variable, add objects to thw list, then loop over it issuing the command. While this works, I am primarily doing this excersize to teach myself programming, so I want to know if there is a more elegant solution than writing code to append, pop, etc. items to a list in an object. Since `list` already contains these functions, i was thinking the correct thing to do would be to extend `list`:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Command = "Script Command"

    def printCommand(self):
        print(self.Command)

class ObjectList(list):
    def printCommand(self):
        for Object in self.LISTCONTENTS:
            Object.printCommand()
```

However, I am at a loss as to how I would tell it to iterate over its own contents. What belongs at `self.LISTCONTENTS`? Where does a `list` object store its contents, and how do you access them from a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate over `self`:

The superclass methods (i.e., `__iter__()`) are all present. Saying `self` in the context of a **for** statement will cause the appropriate methods to be invoked.

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Command = "Script Command"

    def printCommand(self):
        print(self.Command)

class ObjectList(list):
    def printCommand(self):
        for Object in self:
            Object.printCommand()

lst = ObjectList()
lst.append(Object())
lst.append(Object())

lst.printCommand()
```

The way this works is `list` implements `__iter__` which is called behind the scenes when iterating over an object:

```
>>> for e in [1,2,3].__iter__():
...  print(e)
... 
1
2
3
>>> for e in [1,2,3]:
...  print(e)
... 
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

(a) Don't ever create a class called `Object`, that's far too close to `object`.

(b) There is absolutely no need to inherit from `list`, and frankly I doubt the need to use your own class at all.

(c) The normal way to invoke a function on every element of a list is to use `map`. If you need to map with the same function repeatedly, you can use `partial` to bind that function to `map`'s first argument.

Now go look at the documentation.

Comment: Re (c): `map` is not for side effects, neither are list comprehensions. Just use a `for` loop.

Comment: @delnan: There's no reason why you can't use it for side effects. If it bothers you, options include a generator expression, or writing your own non-list-producing iterator function. In any case, my point stands that inheritance is simply unnecessary here.

Comment: Of course it *can* be, but it's not idiomatic. A `for` loop is the correct (as in, widely accepted) choice - not that weirdness OP proposed, as you state correctly.

Comment: @delnan: A for loop is idiomatic, but as it isn't a first-class object, it's not, for example, re-usable.

Comment: How often does a loop alone, without anything else, need to be a first-class object (an assignment statement isn't a first class object either, but I dare say no sane man uses `locals().__setitem__` instead)? In the rare case it would come handy, wrapping it in a function is easy enough. How can an additional unneeded (definitely in this case, even if you disagree in general) property overrule an idiom?

Comment: @delnan: The OP was/is planning on using an object to do this, which suggests that they need reification for whatever reason.

Comment: Looking at OP's code, he may not even know what reification means ;) As far as I can tell they just wanted a method to call each object's method in whatever way. I believe you're generalizing prematurely. Or in case you want to argue certain functional programming tools are superior to OOP/imperative programming, you're off topic.

Comment: @point b, ofcourse there is!! One method that instantly comes to mind is first/last... some_list.first() It's much better (OOP + less to type/mistakes) to hide away length checking and access by index

Comment: @Metalstorm Instead of inheritance, one could simply use delegation and achieve all of those benefits.